# Changing application locale makes changes to all users (Vaadin)

Tags: localization, locale, vaadin

In my application I set up the locale when the user get into the system to localize the components. Recently I was giving a demo and noticed that the language was switching from English to Dutch without apparent reason. It turned out that the demo server (hosted in a German server) was being accessed at the same time by another person that set it to Dutch and was affecting my English demo and viceversa.

I gave it a try on my machine with different browsers, using Chrome normal and incognito modes, etc to simulate different sessions and the issue is present. Any ideas on how to handle/fix this? I thought Vaadin already handled user sessions on its own but it seems that the application's variables are shared?

Here's what I do in my application to change the locale:

```
@Override
    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        super.setLocale(locale);
        xerb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.bluecubs.xinco.messages.XincoMessages", getLocale());
}
```

Then the xerb resource bundle is used to internationalize the UI. I tried not doing the super call but the result is the same, as if xerb was being modified by various sessions and shared among them.

Any ideas?

Same question on Vaadin's forum: https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1091312

**Edit**

Using ThreadLocal pattern I added outputs to when each instance is obtained and I see different instances for each browser. (i.e. com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.vaadin.Xinco@2114ed for the first one and com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.vaadin.Xinco@fd68fe for the second browser) so I believe the model is used correctly. Sadly I still see the same issue.

Comment: What exactly is `xerb`? Is it field in the class that extends `com.vaadin.Application`?

Comment: Just a ResourceBundle used for internationalization. It is not static variable. But yes a field in the class that extends com.vaadin.Application

Comment: So how are you accessing this `xerb` field from other classes then? Are you using [ThreadLocal pattern](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ThreadLocal%20Pattern)?

Comment: xerb is a local variable in the application. It does have a a public method to access it: public ResourceBundle getResource() but it is called from an instance of the application sent to custom components created from the application (i.e. referring to the same context IMO)

Comment: Looking at the ThreadLocal pattern, not using it for sure.

Comment: Arthur can you write a proper answer using ThreadLocal pattern to award the points? Although it ended up being mostly a code bug you pointer about ThreadLocal pattern was the key piece.

Comment: Glad you found the bug! Of course, I think first of all it will be easier for other people to find the answer if they run into the same problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to apply [ThreadLocal pattern](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ThreadLocal%20Pattern) to access the `Application` instance from other controls in the app. This way, it's more explicit whenever you try to obtain some session-specific information. It's also quite widespread in Vaadin applications, so the code may be more readable.

Passing the reference to the fields of your `Application` indirectly by making it an outer class for anonymous listeners can lead to hard to detect bugs, because it can be difficult to work out the exact moment of creating the controls and what `ResourceBundle` was referenced at that very point.

Comment: Besides a bug in my code, using ThreadLocal pattern was the real key to solving this.

Comment: there is a good implementation of this pattern under apache license http://code.google.com/p/dellroad-stuff/source/browse/trunk/src/java/org/dellroad/stuff/vaadin/ContextApplication.java

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin does handle user sessions and keeps variables separate, so this is not normal behavior. The 'xerb' field must be somehow shared between users. The only a few reasons for this that I can think of right now are

1. `xerb` is a static field
2. the `ResourceBundle` pointed to by `xerb` is the same (static) one
3. The actual `Application` instance is shared between users

You already said #1 is not the cause. #2 might be it, but I don't know if that would be possible. #3 would be possible if you have a custom ApplicationServlet containing a bug that causes it to return the same instance of Application for all users. Or perhaps there is some injection mechanism injecting the same thing in all Applications?

Without more information it's impossible to know what's actually going on.

HTH

Comment: I don't quite understand #2. For me 1 and 2 are the same. When you declare the ResourceBundle it refers to a properties file that can't be modified at run time. If Vaadin handles user sessions then non static variables shouldn't be shared among instances. There is no custom application servlet. No injection mechanism (at least introduced by me). What other type of information you would like to know? Just in case the source code is here: https://xinco.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/xinco/trunk