# Setting default locale for Vaadin application

Tags: locale, vaadin

Maybe this question was asked but I couldn't find. I am new to Vaadin. And how can I set default locale for Vaadin application.

Comment: may be this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023460/changing-application-locale-makes-changes-to-all-users-vaadin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vaadin 6 : [Application#setLocale(Locale)](https://vaadin.com/api/6.8.9/com/vaadin/Application.html#setLocale(java.util.Locale))

Vaadin 7 : [VaadinSession#setLocale(Locale)](https://vaadin.com/api/7.0.5/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html#setLocale(java.util.Locale)) e.g. `VaadinSession.getCurrent().setLocale();`

Example code for Vaadin 7, as might be used in the `init` method of UI.

```java
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
this.setLocale( locale ); // Call to affect this current UI. Workaround for bug/issue: http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12350
this.getSession().setLocale( locale ); // Affects only future UI instances, not current one. See workaround in line above.
// VaadinSession.getCurrent().setLocale( locale ); // Alternative to "this.getSession".
```

Comment: This answer inspired me to expand the Vaadin Wiki page on this topic: [Remember to the set the Locale](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Remember+to+the+set+the+Locale). I added example code and some discussion.

Comment: Note that Vaadin 7 has a **serious design issue** (or bug) ([ticket # 12350](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12350)) where setting locale on VaadinSession does not take proper effect in the already existing UI object(s). The workaround is simple: [a] call `setLocale` on the current UI(s) to affect them, as well as [b] calling `setLocale` on the VaadinSession to affect future UI objects. See the wiki link in my comment above for discussion and example app.